# how to show button if there are two roles Lotus Formula script

Tags: lotus-domino, lotus-formula

I have a Page in Lotus, which has an action button.
This button must be not visible when user is not part of role Admin or Supervisor.
The way i did this is by adding this formula:

@IsNotMember("[Admin]"; @UserRoles) | @IsNotMember("[Supervisor]"; @UserRoles)

But it does not work..
If I have only 1, like: @IsNotMember("[Admin]"; @UserRoles) And the role Admin, then as admin I can see it.

But I also would like to have that if user is from role Supervisor and not Admin that he still can see the button.

What to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Formula

```
 @IsNotMember("[Admin]" : "[Supervisor]"; @UserRoles)
```

returns @True if user has neither role "[Admin]" nor "[Supervisor]". Use this as hide-when formula for your button. Only Admins and Supervisors will see the button then.

Answer (score 4):

Knut's answer is correct. My answer shows why, and gives an approach to hide-whens that almost always makes them easier to figure out.

Notes has been using hide-when formulas forever, but people really tend to think in terms of see-when in their requirements! We know when we want to see things (when we're Supervisors or Admins in this case). And we're really bad at turning those see-when requirements into hide-when formulas because we're really bad at remembering [DeMorgan's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws), which says things like:   ^(P & Q) == (^P | ^Q)

So if we state the requirement this way:

```
Hide when the user isn't a Supervisor or an Admin
```

we tend to have trouble turning it into the correct formula with two @IsNotMember calls (which are implicitly logical Nots), because we forget that Ors have to turn into Ands in order to get it right. But if we think of it this way:

```
See when the user is an Admin or the user is an Supervisor
```

It's easy to see how to express it:

```
@IsMember("[Supervisor]"; @UserRoles) | @IsMember("[Admin]"; @UserRoles);
```

Or using the power of formula language lists, we can shorten that to this :

```
@IsMember("[Supervisor]": "[Admin]" ; @UserRoles);
```

To turn that into the equivalent hide-when, all you need to do is put a logical Not around it like this:

```
! (@IsMember("[Supervisor]": "[Admin]" ; @UserRoles));
```

You can do that with any see-when formula - just surround it with parenthesis and put a ! in front of it, but in the special case of a formula that just uses @IsMember, you can just change it to @IsNotMember, which brings it back to Knut's solution.

Comment: Gotta love that elementary logic :-)

Comment: Shorthand version which I find easier:
!(@userroles = "[Admin]" : "[Supervisor]");

- the ! turns a hide-when into a show-when (easier to think about, as Richard says)
- the "=" runs through all combinations of the @userroles list and the list to compare with, so if the user has Admin or Supervisor, theyll see the button.